# How to detect two adjacent identical characters in Haskell using list comprehension and recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a function `detadj :: String -> Bool` that takes a string and returns true if
the string contains two adjacent characters that are identical. For example:

```
detadj "" == False
detadj "s" == False
detadj "ss" == True
detadj "Misisipi" == False
detadj "Mississippi" == True
detadj "single-dash" == False
detadj "double--dash" == True
```

I have two versions of the function one in list comprehension, which is faulty in many cases, but the most prevalent one is when `detadjlc ["ss"]` which will output an empty list due to the usage of the `(x:y:xs)` bit:

```
detadjlc :: String -> Bool
detadjlc [] = False
detadjlc [x] = False
detadjlc (x:y:xs) = head[ x == y && isAlpha x == isAlpha y | (x,y) <- zip (x:y:xs) xs ]
```

And recursion (this does not work when the input is something like `detadjr [" ee"]` which produces `False` instead of `True`):

```
detadjr :: String -> Bool
detadjr [] = False
detadjr [x] = False
detadjr (x:y:xs) | x == y = True
           | otherwise = d xs
```

What are some ways to fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive function is fine, except for one small detail: you forgot to put `y` back on the list for the recursive call. (I assume `d` is a typo for `detadjr`.) Just because `x` and `y` are different doesn't mean `y` and the first character of `xs` might not be the same.

```
detadjr :: String -> Bool
detadjr (x:y:xs) = (x == y) || detadjr (y:xs)
detadjr _ = False
```

(If you check strings of 2 or more characters first, then singleton and empty lists can be collapsed into a single base case.)

Answer (score 3):

Following is an iterative solution using list comprehension. We create a list of tuples containing adjacent elements of the input list. Then we compare those elements in the tuple.

```hs
detadjlc :: String -> Bool
detadjlc xs = or [x == y | (x, y) <- zip xs (tail xs)]
```

The recursive solution is best done as @chepner already posted.